# how to solve org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-cargo

whenever I up the application by through CMD it is getting up, but the same code if I run through eclipse, getting the below mentioned error...

```
[DEBUG] [URLDeployableMonitor] Checking URL [http://localhost:8080/cargocpc/index.html] for status using a timeout of [120000] ms...
[DEBUG] [URLDeployableMonitor] URL [http://localhost:8080/cargocpc/index.html] is not responding: 400 Cycle Detected
[DEBUG] [URLDeployableMonitor] Notifying monitor listener [org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.DeployerWatchdog@a55f49]
[INFO] [yer.DeployerWatchdog] Deployable [http://localhost:8080/cargocpc/index.html] failed to finish deploying within the timeout period [120000]. The Deployable state is thus unknown.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to start the Tomcat 6.x container.
Deployable [http://localhost:8080/cargocpc/index.html] failed to finish deploying within the timeout period [120000]. The Deployable state is thus unknown.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Trace
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to start the Tomcat 6.x container.
.
.
.
.

Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Deployable [http://localhost:8080/cargocpc/index.html] failed to finish deploying within the timeout period [120000]. The Deployable state is thus unknown.

at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.DeployerWatchdog.watch (DeployerWatchdog.java:111)**
```

but if I run through command prompt its getting up... why in eclipse am facing this issue and how to solve that?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Set timeout to 0 in the execution portion of the Maven Cargo plugin config to disable the URL Deployable Monitor. Also comment out the pingURL & pingTimeout elements

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven3-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <containerId>tomcat9x</containerId>
                <containerUrl>file:///C://APPS/tomcat-9.0.29.zip</containerUrl>
                <container>
                    <containerId>tomcat9x</containerId>
                    <type>standalone</type>
                </container>
                <deployables>
                    <deployable>
                        <artifactId>MYAPP</artifactId>
                        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                        <type>war</type>
                        <location>deploy/generic/jclass/MYAPP.war</location>
                        <!-- <pingURL>http://127.0.0.1:8080/MYAPP/index.jsp</pingURL> -->
                        <!-- <pingTimeout>150000</pingTimeout> -->
                    </deployable>
                </deployables>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-server</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <container>
                            <timeout>0</timeout>
                        </container>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-server</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <container>
                            <timeout>0</timeout>
                        </container>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Open the servers view
- double click your tomcat server
- click on Timeouts section
- increase start up time out

Comment: I increased the timeout to 300000, still getting the same error..          [DEBUG] [URLDeployableMonitor] Checking URL [http://localhost:8080/cargocpc/index.html] for status using a timeout of [300000] ms...    [DEBUG] [URLDeployableMonitor] URL [http://localhost:8080/cargocpc/index.html] is not responding: 400 Cycle Detected [DEBUG] [URLDeployableMonitor] Notifying monitor listener [org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.DeployerWatchdog@57962c][yer.DeployerWatchdog]Deployable[http://localhost:8080/cargocpc/index.html] failed to finish deploying within the timeout period [300000].

Comment: something seems wrong with configuration that makes very slooow startup

Comment: If I run the same code through cmd, its getting up with 120000 as timeout itself..   In console **[DEBUG] [URLDeployableMonitor] Checking URL [http://localhost:8080/cargocpc/index.html] for status using a timeout of [300000] ms...[DEBUG] [URLDeployableMonitor] URL [http://localhost:8080/cargocpc/index.html] is not responding: 400 Cycle Detected
[DEBUG] [URLDeployableMonitor] Notifying monitor listener [org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.DeployerWatchdog@18a2456]**
this getting printed repeatedly till the timeout. Is that 400 cycle detected will be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

*NOTE: Edited from original to add context.*

You can try increasing the timeout value that Cargo uses while waiting for Tomcat to start/stop.

Example:

```xml
<container>
  [...]
  <timeout>180000</timeout>
  [...]
</container>
```

Check this description in Cargo website:

https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Container+Timeout.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Hibernate, make sure your database connection details in your properties file are correct. In my case cargo was timing out because my database username and password were incorrect.